# Need to create a flag column based on a few conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consists municipality CODE column, yield and year. I need create a single column called Quality Flag, that should have flags of 0, 1 and 2 for certain conditions.

1. Quality flag - 0 - if three consecutive or more years' yield values are not same for each municipality.
2. Quality flag - 1 - For each municipality, if three consecutive or more years' yield values are same, assign all the years having same yield values, quality flag of 1.
3. Quality flag - 2 - if yield value is more than 3 SD from mean value of yield, assign that row as Quality flag -2.

I have written the R code

It is assigning quality flag -2 correctly, but flag - 0 and 1 not according to the conditions.

The output, for example one municipality look like this. But it is not correct.[image: sample]

I did try this

```
# Step 1: Create a new column called 'Quality_Flag'
yield_area_long$Quality_Flag <- NA

# Step 2: Assign Quality Flag based on consecutive same yield values
df <- yield_area_long %>%
  group_by(CODE)%>%
  mutate(
    consecutive_years = cumsum(yield = lag(yield, default = first(yield))) &
      cumsum(yield = lead(yield, default = last(yield)))) 
  ungroup()


# Step 3: Identify high outliers (more than 3 standard deviations from mean)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(CODE) %>% mutate(
    consecutive_flag = case_when(
      consecutive_years >= 3 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    outlier_flag = case_when(abs(yield - mean(yield, na.rm = TRUE)) > 3 * sd(yield, na.rm = TRUE) ~ 2,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    Quality_Flag = pmax(consecutive_flag, outlier_flag, 0) # Ensure the minimum is 0
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Remove the temporary columns
df$consecutive_years <- NULL
df$consecutive_flag <- NULL
df$outlier_flag <- NULL
```

But it is not correctly assigning 0 and 1 flag.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: When you [edit] your question to provide usable data, please include the expected output for your `Output_Flag` column. If the image of your data is correct, then I suggest your data is not varied enough to trigger the different responses you need: your sample data should trigger one or more of each of your levels (perhaps two of each?) so that you can be certain the code suggestions you get are valid.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I put my tried code in code block. Didn't put as an image. Yeah, data just for understanding, I copied and attached there.

Comment: There still is no data and there still is no correct expected output. Add a suitable part of the data using `dput()` (e.g. above: What is `yield_area_long`?) and then add the expected output column for this data. Also, avoid using screenshots and put your expected output into R code or a [table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow).